# pip install "cv2"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pip, module

```py
import cv2
import argparse
import pytesseract
```

in above code snippet, I want to specifically install `cv2` module.

So I tried this command,

```bash
pip install cv2 #but it shows that there is no module exists
```

When I try to install this library, it shows this error message.
[Screenshot`Error` message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFyBa.png)

I think it's not the right command to install.
Can anyone assist me in this?

A way to install the `cv2` python module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: In order to install a module, is this the correct command to install it?